# How do I pass more than one parameter into a link_to call where I specify controller and action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, link-to

I am using a link_to to initiate a controller method that requires two parameters in order to perform the steps I need it to take.  I can't seem to get the syntax right, and I'm wondering if it is because you can't pass more than one parameter in using this particular syntax.  Here is what I have so far:

```
<%= link_to 'Select',
            {controller: 'groups',
             action: 'associate_subgroup_with_org',
             organization_id: organization.id,
             subgroup_id: @activity.group.id},
            class: 'button' %>

def associate_subgroup_with_org
    @organization = Group.find(params[:organization_id])
    @subgroup = Group.find(params[:subgroup_id])
    @subgroup.parent_group_id = @organization.id

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

The link is not working and I never enter my controller action `associate_subgroup_with_org`.  Can someone help me get the syntax right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a route like this:

```
get '/groups/associate_subgroup_with_org' => 'groups#associate_subgroup_with_org', :as => :associate_subgroup
```

And you can send any no. of parameters with link_to:

```
<%= link_to 'Select',
            {controller: 'groups',
             action: 'associate_subgroup_with_org',
             organization_id: organization.id,
             subgroup_id: @activity.group.id},
            class: 'button' %>
```

Or,

```
<%= link_to 'Select',associate_subgroup_path(organization_id: organization.id, subgroup_id: @activity.group.id),class: 'button' %>
```

Comment: so is making a route a requirement as soon as there is more than one parameter, or do you need to have a route defined in routes.rb for every controller/action paring?

Comment: rails follows mvc architecture and it is compulsory to define a route to hit some action according to flow of mvc. It is decided by route definition, that which url should hit some particular action

Comment: So, I've noticed in the past that with one parameter or none, a link_to helper will accept passing in a `:controller` and an `:action`, even if there isn't a route defined in routes.rb.  Is this not what is supposed to happen?

Comment: You might be using resources for that controller in route file. Try to comment all routes in your routes.rb file and then hit that action.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify it in your routes. Something like this:

```
get "/groups/:id/subgroup/:state" => "groups#subgroup", :as => :subgroup
```

And write the link like:

```
subgroup_path(@organization, @subgroup)
```

With whatever symbols you're using.

Comment: so if I'm only passing one parameter, this isn't a requirement any more?  As I try this, can you explain why you have to add this route?

Comment: The route needs to be able to interpret the two `params[:this]`, as far as I know. It works for me.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand.  I used a variation of your suggestion and I'm close to the desired functionality.  But a follow up question I have is: how do I avoid letting someone just type this url path in with bogus parameters, potentially hacking or breaking the process I'm trying to facilitate?

Comment: That's the problem with passing params in the URL: people can type anything. I guess in the controller you could write a check that only accepts subgroups from `Group.all` or from a list or something.

Answer (score 1):

Using controller and actions in link_to/form_url is not recommended. I guess you have a groups resources, I mean in routes.rb something like `resources :groups`. if so then add a collection method there like:

```
resources :groups do
  #....
  post :associate_subgroup_with_org
end
```

Now you can use `associate_subgroup_with_org_groups_path(p1: v1, p2: v2, .....)`

Or you can define one named route as:

```
post 'groups/associate_subgroup_with_org', as: :associate_subgroup_with_org
```

Now you can use `associate_subgroup_with_org_path(p1: v1, p2: v2, .....)`

Hope its clear